# How do I add a function to a model that doesn't require a model instance?

Tags: python, django, class, models

So I've been trying to add a model function in Django that takes arguments and then inserts X number of new records into the database.

Why isn't it possible to do `MyModel.MyFunction()`? Do I need to make an instance of it first?

If so, is there a better way of achieving the result I desire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly do this, you just need to make it a [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    @classmethod
    def my_function(cls):
        new_instance = cls(...)
        new_instance.save()
        # etc...
```